# How do I prove the "mean value property" for Helmholtz equation?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, special-functions, harmonic-analysis, bessel-functions

Suppose $u: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^2$ function that satisfies the Helmholtz equation $-\Delta u = \lambda u$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

I am trying to prove something that looks like a modified mean value property, namely that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_{\partial B(z_0,r)} u \,\mathrm{d}\Gamma = \begin{cases} u(z_0) \cdot J_0(\sqrt{\lambda} r) &\quad \text{if } \lambda > 0\\ u(z_0) &\quad\text{if } \lambda = 0\\ u(z_0) \cdot I_0(\sqrt{-\lambda} r) &\quad\text{if }\lambda < 0\end{cases}$$

I used polar coordinates and tried to approach the equation with separation of variables, saying that $u(r, \theta) = R(r) \Theta(\theta)$. I got $\Theta(\theta) = C_1 e^{i m \theta} + C_2 e^{- i m \theta}$, from the equation
$$ \partial_{\theta}^2 \Theta = - C \Theta $$

For $R(r)$, I got the (modified / standard, depending on $\lambda$) Bessel equation. However, I don't know how to proceed. If $\Theta(\theta)$ was a harmonic function, I could simply integrate and put the Bessel part before the integral and then apply the mean value theorem. However, I am stuck, since it is not a harmonic function.

Ultimately, I have three questions;

1. What is the justification for using separation of variables? I have used it, but I don't know if I can, since the statements is phrased for *every* solution of the Helmholtz equation; what if there are solutions that don't have separated variables?
2. When solving the Bessel equation, we get multiple solutions $J_m$ and when solving the modified Bessel equations, we get multiple solutions $I_m$. Why are there only $J_0$ and $I_0$ in the final result?
3. As mentioned above, how do I proceed to actually show this property?

Comment: In my experience, separation of variables is one of those mathematical tricks you try and see if it works, though some people can see the patterns and predict when it might work. As for whether there are solutions that don't have separated variables, if you can complete your analysis without assuming anything extra on $u$, then that's sufficient to know it works for every solution. If there are solutions that don't have, then you should hit a roadblock in the analysis where you have to make an assumption to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll provide a completely different approach.
Let $\lambda >0 $.
Define the elliptic operator $L:= \Delta + \lambda I$.

1. $ K(x,z_0) = - \dfrac{cos(\sqrt{\lambda}r)}{4\pi r}$ for $r=|x-z_0| $ is a fundamental solution of $Lu = 0$. (check the details)
2. Same goes for $S(x,z_0) = c \dfrac{sin(\sqrt{\lambda}r)}{r}$ for some $c$.

You can gain $K$ and $S$ by finding all the solutions of $Lu=0$ with spherical symmetry.
Now by using $G(x,z_0)= K(x,z_0) + S(x,z_0)$ as the Green function for the problem $Lu=0$ in $B(z_0,r)$ we have:

---

$$\Delta G(r)+ \lambda G(r) = \delta_{z_0}(r), \text{in} \; \;B(z_0,r) \\ G= 0, \; \text{in} \; \; \partial B(z_0,r)$$

where $\delta_{z_0}(r)$ is the dirac function centered at $z_0$.Then use the Green Identity in $B(z_0,r)$

$$ \int _{B(z_0,r)}u\Delta G - G\Delta u dx = \int_{\partial B(z_0,r)} u \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial n} - G \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial n}d\Gamma $$

Now due to the fact that $\Delta u = -\lambda u$ we have

$$\int _{B(z_0,r)}u\Delta G - G\Delta u dx = \int _{B(z_0,r)}u\Delta G + G\lambda u dx = \int _{B(z_0,r)}u(\Delta G + \lambda G )dx = \int _{B(z_0,r)}u \delta_{z_0} dx = u(z_0)$$

Now since $G= 0, \; \text{in} \; \; \partial B(z_0,r)$, we obtain

$$ u(z_0) = \int_{\partial B(z_0,r)}u \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial n} d \Gamma $$

Now we can just calculate the last integral, and by using $G= 0, \; \text{in} \; \; \partial B(z_0,r)$, we can also compute the constant $c$ and at last we obtain:

$$ u(z_0) = \dfrac {\sqrt{\lambda}r}{2 r sin(\sqrt{\lambda}r)} \dfrac{1}{2 \pi r} \int_{\partial B(z_0,r)}u(x)d\Gamma$$

where the last equation is undoubtedly what a "mean value property" of the Helmholtz equation should look like. If $\lambda <0$ we obtain an analogous result, particularly:

$$u(z_0)=\dfrac{\sqrt{-\lambda}r}{2rsinh(\sqrt{-\lambda}r)}\dfrac{1}{2 \pi r} \int_{\partial B(z_0,r)}u(x)d\Gamma$$.

Comment: Fascinating, although probably a bit too advanced for me. But wouldn't your solution combined with the final result I wrote give us an elementary representation of $J_0$ and $I_0$? I find that quite strange.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you calculate $J_0$ and $I_0$, you will ultimately find the expressions appearing in the solution.

Comment: That's weird cause I can't find $J_0$ expressed with elementary functions anywhere on the internet

Comment: Even though generally the Bessel functions are expressed as infinite sums, for me it does not seem that weird eg. for $J_0$ to converge for $n=0$ to the expression I calculated above. Of course I haven't checked it.

Comment: I totally agree, but I would have thought that it is a well known identity and easy to find on the web ... however this isn't the case.

Comment: Maybe my approach gives the mean value property, modulo some constant, before the integral, which is of no significance, and it is possible that it is not exactly $J_0$ but some constant times $J_0$. Because when in (1) I used $K$ as a fundamental solution, it is possible, there can be some constant times $K$, and this will still be a fundamental solution. So maybe, it is not necessary for my -before the integral - constants to be exactly as $J_0$ and $I_0$. I have little to none knowledge about Bessel functions, and that's why I tried to solve this without using them.

Comment: Oh and by the way, I just found out that, when we are talking spherical (like here inside the sphere of radius r), indeed my calculations agree with the Bessel functions. You can check the spherical Bessel functions paragraph at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function .

Comment: On a second though this is all I want :)

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful to you!